# can't figure my integral mistake

Tags: calculus, integration

I have question involving solving for the anti derivative and wonder where my math goes wrong in this equation:
: **Find $f(x)$ if $f'''(x)=24x$**

$$f"(x) = 12x^2+C \\ f'(x) = 4x^3 +Cx +D \\ f(x) = x^4 + (Cx^2)/2 + DX + E$$

My antiderivate in the last step I thought was:
$$ f(x) = 4 * (1/4)x^{(3+1)} + C*(1/2)x^{(1+1)} + DX + E$$

The answer given in the book:
$$ f(x) = x^4 + Cx^2 + DX + E$$

Any hints where I go wrong in my math?

Comment: The two answers are equivalent. Just rename the $C$'s book with $C/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant is arbitrary i.e. just call it $C'$ and $\frac{C'}2=C$ and you will have the same answer.

Comment: Awe I see.  That makes complete sense.